# How do I add a select time parameter to reporting services

Tags: reporting-services, report

I need to create a report that allows the user to give date and time range to report.  I can set up the startdate and enddate but I can't seem to figure out how to add starttime and endtime.  This is a report where they want to view what was processed between a certain date and time.

Comment: Clarify, do you mean you don't understand how to alter the T-SQL to query using your date parameters or...?

Answer (score 2):

In SSRS, there is only one Parameter data type that allows you to enter date and time values - DateTime, which is a combined date and time type.

You *could* set up separate parameters for each of the date and time values of the start and end of your selection range, but I recommend that you use one parameter for start datetime, and one parameter for end datetime. You should specify your record selection criteria so that the dataset date and time value is between the start and end datetime parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i am aware they shoudl be able to type in a time after the date part in the datetime parameter.